# MyAnimeList REST API limitations

Tags: c#, html

I'm currently developing a C# API that connects to MAL for developing clients applications.

My problem is that currently I'm using the REST API of MAL documented in this page: http://myanimelist.net/modules.php?go=api#animevalues

Everything there function wonderfully, but my problem is that with only that services I cannot query about a user anime list or manga list. Neither for their score, progression, etc of their anime/manga.

My question is that I'm wrong and that info can be obtain with that API?

I know that I can access a user animelist (or mangalist) like: http://myanimelist.net/animelist/ and parse the content to obtain the info. But I was wondering if I can get that info with the REST API that is more robust (not as weak to changes in the page as parsing the html).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems odd that the API does not appear to have this capability, but I also couldn’t find any information on it.

What you can use however is the following URL:

```
http://myanimelist.net/malappinfo.php?u=<username>
```

Apart from the username, it accepts a `type` parameter to query either the `anime` or `manga` list. There appears to be also a `status` parameter, but I have no idea how that works.

I also just found [this thread](http://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=694489) on the topic.

Comment: Thanks. That solves the problem. As you say seams that nobody knows what it does. Anyway with all the info I can filter it later.